# jQuery CSS Scoping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am in a situation where I have two WordPress plugins that include the jquery-ui.css and the last plugin that gets loaded overwrites the first plugin's css. I would like both themes to load. I know the jQuery theme builder supports CSS scoping, but neither of these plugins take advantage of this feature, and editing the plugin isn't a reasonable option (since changes will be overwritten next time I update the plugin). Is there any way I can programmatically implement the scoping, by adding some JavaScript to my theme?

Comment: Are both Wordpress plug-ins on the same physical page?

Comment: yes, both plugins are on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to be able to scope at least one of the plugins' output by marking its container (or use additional wrapping ) by some `class`. For that `class` to take effect you need to download a [new package build](http://jqueryui.com/download/) filling `CSS Scope` with your `class` selector that would be `.class`. `Theme Folder Name` is where your new scoped css will be into. Check [this page](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/using_multiple_jquery_ui_themes_on_a_single_page/) for details.

[image].

**WordPress**

To keep things nice and clear under WordPress, register new CSS. Inside your theme's `functions.php`:

```
wp_register_style( 'myScopedjQueryUICss', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scopedjQueryUICssDirectory/ui.all.css' );
```

Last, enqueue this styles where you need them. Common way to do that is to hook following line to `wp_print_styles` action.

```
function hookScopedCss() { 
   if ( wp_style_is( 'myScopedjQueryUICss' ) || 
        wp_style_is( 'myScopedjQueryUICss', 'done' ) )
   { return; }
   wp_enqueue_style( 'myScopedjQueryUICss' );
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'hookScopedCss' );
```